# How to make unit testing when the returned value of method is a mock expectation

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-boot-test, spy

Return of method "ContractService" is a return value of method "checkPgwContract". I'm already mock the ContractService class and ContractServiceManager class, but method of checkPgwContract always passed in my unit test.

**ContractServiceImpl**

```
@Override
public List getListOfContractBy(String contractNo) {
List<OasysContract> oasysContractList = oasysContractRepository.findByContractNumber(contractNo);
if (!oasysContractList.isEmpty()) {
        return oasysContractList;
    } else {
        List<Contract> pgwContractList = contractRepository.findContractsByContractNumber(contractNo);
        if (!pgwContractList.isEmpty()) {
            return contractServiceManager.checkPgwContract(pgwContractList);
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList();
}
```

**ContractServiceManagerImpl**

```
private boolean checkHCP(String contractNumber) {
    return contractRepository.findContractByExpiredDate(contractNumber) != null ? true : false;
}

private String checkIsFullyPaid(String contractNumber) {
    return contractRepository.getFullyPaid(contractNumber);
}

@Override
public List<Contract> checkPgwContract(List<Contract> contractList) {
    for (Contract contract : contractList) {
        //check paymentType
        if (contract.getPaymentType() != null &&
                contract.getPaymentType().equals(PAYMENT_TYPE_HCP)) {
            if (checkHCP(contract.getContractNumber())) {
                //check isFullyPaid
                if (checkIsFullyPaid(contract.getContractNumber()).equals(FLAG_YES)) {
                    return new ArrayList<>();
                }
            } else {
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
    }
    return contractList;
}
```

**UnitTest**

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private ContractServiceImpl service;

@Mock
ContractRepository contractRepository;

@Mock
OasysContractRepository oasysContractRepository;

@Mock
ContractServiceManager serviceManager;


public static final String contractNumber = "3900006835";

@Test
public void getListOfContractBy_hcp_success() {
    List<OasysContract> oasysContractList = new ArrayList<>();
    oasysContractList.isEmpty();

    List<Contract> contractList = new ArrayList<>();
    contractList.add(BuildUtil.buildContract());

    //mock
    Mockito.doReturn(oasysContractList).when(oasysContractRepository).findByContractNumber(contractNumber);
    Mockito.doReturn(BuildUtil.buildContractList()).when(contractRepository).findContractsByContractNumber(contractNumber);
    Mockito.doReturn(contractList).when(serviceManager).checkPgwContract(contractList);
    Mockito.doReturn(BuildUtil.buildContract()).when(contractRepository).findContractByExpiredDate(contractNumber);
    Mockito.doReturn("N").when(contractRepository).getFullyPaid(contractNumber);


    //test
    List<Contract> contracts = service.getListOfContractBy(contractNumber);

    System.out.println(contracts);

    assert(!contracts.isEmpty());
}
```

Now, the value of contracts parameter is empty. It should be return contractList. I think because mock of method checkPgwContract is ignored.

My test will still pass, which is obviously wrong, so how should I test this?

Comment: What's in BuildUtil.buildContractList()?

Comment: Are you sure that your `contractServiceManager` mock is properly injected into your `ContractServiceImpl` service? As you did not add a constructor for your class I assume `field injection` is used, but that would require the variable in your test (`serviceManager`) to have the same name as the variable in your class under test (`contractServiceManager`).

Answer (score 1):

This line doesn't make sense to me: `Mockito.doReturn(contractList).when(serviceManager).checkPgwContract(contractList);`

Your method `checkPgwContract()` won't be called with `contractList` as parameter so it will not trigger the doReturn from Mockito.
It will be called with whatever `BuildUtil.buildContractList()` returns in your line above: 
`Mockito.doReturn(BuildUtil.buildContractList()).when(contractRepository).findContractsByContractNumber(contractNumber);`